# How do you get the index of a character in a string when it's less than your starting index?

Tags: c#, indexof, substring

As per my question, I want to get the index of the first comma prior to my current starting index. To give an example of the data I have a string like this:

`Bob Green;PD,Andy Richards;BD,Frank Williams;OW,James Clack;PM`

The string contains elements setup as `[Persons Name];[Role]`, so the name is separated from the role by a `;` (semi-colon) and each element is separated from each other with a `,` (comma).

The elements in the string can be in any order, so the reason for my question is that I want to get the person's name out for the role `OW`. My initial thoughts were to get the index of `;OW,` and somehow work back from there. I can obviously loop backwards through the string from my starting index checking to see if the character is a comma but that seems inefficient, so is there a better way to achieve this?

***EDIT***

To clarify, I only want to get the name associated with the role OW. This role SHOULD only occur in the string once. If it doesn't then I'm happy to only get the first occurrence, which I think IndexOf(";OW,") will do. I don't need the other roles or names, just the name associated with OW.

Also, roles will only ever be 2 characters long. As Matt Burland pointed out, if it's at the end of the string it won't have a trailing comma. However, I can amend my indexof to simply search for ";OW" as roles are only 2 characters long.

Comment: `String.LastIndexOf`?

Comment: Both [String.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xkyx09y(v=vs.110).aspx) and [String.LastIndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1tw91fa3(v=vs.110).aspx) have overloads that take a starting index to search from. As to efficiency, I don't think you can do better than O(n) here.

Comment: Are the roles unique or can there be multiple of the same one?

Comment: But a better way would be to probably parse your string into a collection (perhaps `Dictionary<string,string>` keyed on role), so you can then easily look up any role and find the associated person.

Comment: I don't think it's particularly inefficient. However if this is going to run many times on the same string, then a solution like @MattBurland mentioned is better.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever How would LastIndexOf help? I basically want the index of the first comma prior to the index of the ';' before OW. I thought LastIndexOf simply gives you the last index of something in a string.

Comment: @ZoomVirus - there may be multiples.

Comment: @sr28 Yes, it does - but you can pass in a starting position to say "start from here rather then the end of the string"

Comment: @dstanley so do you want all of them or just the first ow?

Comment: @ZoomVirus Ask the OP, not me.

Comment: @ZoomVirus - I only want the name associated with the role OW, nothing else.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - The reason is that I don't know where the element for 'OW' will be in the string. My thoughts were to initially search for the role by getting the index of ';OW,' and then get the name associated with it by somehow working backwards until I reach a comma (indicates I've hit a new element) and then add 1 to that index. If you could give me an example using just String.IndexOf then I'm all ears.

Comment: @sr28: sorry, i've already deleted my comment before you've posted yours. I've seen that you don't want to look behind but before an index. So to answer the title-question(which seems not to answer the question), take the part of the string you want to search and use `LastIndexOf`: `str.Remove(startIndex).LastIndexOf(',');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`string.LastIndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1tw91fa3(v=vs.110).aspx) overload that includes the starting position:

```
string s = "Bob Green;PD,Andy Richards;BD,Frank Williams;OW,James Clack;PM";
int startRole = s.IndexOf(";OW");
int startName = s.LastIndexOf(',',startRole) + 1;  // start at the semicolon before the role
string name s.Substring(startName,(startRole-startName));
```

Note that there are edge cases that need to be considered:

- Are all roles two characters (e.g. could there be a `OWX` role)?
- If the `OW` role is the first in the list there will be no comma before it
- Are there multiple `OW` roles?  If so you could use a `while` loop and just start the search at the end of the previous role string.

Comment: In the question, the OP talked about searching for `;OW,` which fixes the first edge case. Unfortunately, it introduces another edge case where `OW` is the last in the string and isn't followed by a `,`. A regex would probably be useful for solving both of your first two edge cases. Something like `(;OW,|^OW,|;OW$)`

Comment: @MattBurland - good point. I'd not thought of it being at the end of the string. However, I could really just search for ';OW' as roles can only be 2 characters.

Comment: I've added a check if it's the first element of the string, but other than that does what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use `String.Split(',')` to split your string on the comma into an Array. Then make a custom object:

```
public RoledPerson{
    public string Person;
    public string Role;

    public RoledPerson(string input){
        string[] splitInput = input.Split(';');
        Person = splitInput[0];
        Role = splitInput[1];
    }
}
```

Then you can convert your string into an Enumerable as follows:

```
var RoledPersons inputstring.Split(',').Select(string => new RoledPerson(string));
```

Then you can just find whatever RoledPerson has OW as his role:

```
var RoledPersonsWithRole = RoledPersons.Where(roledperson => roledperson.Role == "OW");
```

As Matt Burland said, you can also do this with a `Dictionary<string, string>`. I'll leave how to work this out to you. However, this doesn't support multiple keys with the same name, so this won't work if you have the same role multiple times.

Disclaimer: there might be errors in here.

Comment: This seems fairly long winded just to get out 1 name. Also, the string could be very long, with lots of roles, so I would be spending lots of time splitting out roles that aren't useful to me.

Comment: +1 because I think using a typed object and not searching strings (especially if you need to do it more than once) is the better approach. However, your answer doesn't actually include finding the person with a role of `OW`

Comment: @sr28: There's a lot of context missing from your question, so it's hard to say. If you are only looking for a single result from your string and only once, then a quick and dirty string search (see D Stanley's answer) is fine. If you need to search for multiple people in the string, then converting this into a sensible data structure is going to be more efficient and much easier to maintain.

Comment: @sr28 Is it long-winded? probably. Can it be shorter and faster? probably. However, it's far easier to read than a string manipulation, and I personally think it's slightly more robust, because it won't fail if it doesn't find the index.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs - whether it's easier to read is subjective. As for being more robust adding in a check for whether the IndexOf() returns -1 should cover almost all situations I need. However, if I was looking to do this multiple times for different roles then it would be a good answer.

Answer (score 4):

how about a regular expression. this should work:

```
string role = "OW";
string str = "Bob Green;PD,Andy Richards;BD,Frank Williams;OW,James Clack;PM";
string pattern = "([^,]*);" + role;
var match = Regex.Match(str, pattern);
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic way to get all `OW` not just the first or the last one. Feed in `OW` to the second function.

```
class stringSections
{
    private List<string> role = new List<string>();
    private List<string> name = new List<string>();

    public void Input(string input)
    {
        string temp = "";
        for(int i =0;i<input.Length;i++)
        {
            if(input[i]==';')
            {
                name.Add(temp);
                temp = "";
            } else if(input[i]==',')
            {
                role.Add(temp);
                temp = "";
            } else
            {
                temp += input[i];
            }
        }
    }

    public List<string> GetAll(string prole)
    {
         List<string> reterners = new List<string>();

         for(int i = 0; i < role.Count;i++)
        {
            if (role[i] == prole)
            {
                reterners.Add(name[i]);
            }
        }
         return reterners;
    }
}
```

Comment: Keeping parallel lists like that is usually a poor design. Use a class or a `Dictionary<string,List<string>>`

Answer (score 0):

To handle the edge cases raised by @D Stanley:

```
    var s = "Bob Williams;OW,Bob Green;PD,Frank Williams;OW,Andy Richards;BD,James Clack;PM,Dave Williams;OW";
    var r = new Regex("(;OW,|^OW,|;OW$)");
    if (r.IsMatch(s)) 
    {
        foreach (Match m in r.Matches(s)) 
        {
            var rIdx = m.Index;
            var pIdx = s.LastIndexOf(",",rIdx);
            var person = s.Substring(pIdx + 1, rIdx - pIdx - 1);
            Console.WriteLine(person);
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Role not found");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure my 'solution' worked I coded a quick apsx web form with the following :

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageContent" runat="server">
<asp:HiddenField ID="TestString" runat="server" Value="Bob Green;PD,Andy Richards;BD,Frank Williams;OW,James Clack;PM" />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Find people in role"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="RoleToFind" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br /><br />
<asp:TextBox ID="Result" runat="server" Rows="10" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="294px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="SearchButton" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="SearchButton_Click" />
```

I then created a class as per Nate's answer

```
    [Serializable]
public class RolePerson
{
    public string Person { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

And finally in the code behind the aspx page I have added the following:

```
    public partial class teststack : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<RolePerson> lrp = new List<RolePerson>();

        // Get the string from the hidden field
        string strData = this.TestString.Value;
        // split the string into an array each value in the array haveing name;role
        string[] strRecords = strData.Split(new Char[] {','});
        // process the array and add to the list
        foreach (string s in strRecords)
        {
            string[] strRecord = s.Split(new Char[] { ';' });
            lrp.Add(new RolePerson{
                Person = strRecord[0],
                Role = strRecord[1]
            });
        }
        // Find the person for the specified role
        FindPerson(lrp, this.RoleToFind.Text);
    }

    //Find the people for the specified role and add to the results textbox
    private void FindPerson(List<RolePerson> lrp, string strRole)
    {
        this.Result.Text = null;
        string strResults = string.Empty;
        foreach (RolePerson rp in lrp)
        {
            if (rp.Role == strRole)
                strResults = strResults + rp.Person + "\r\n";
        }
        this.Result.Text = strResults;
    }
}
```

And the result :

[image: Screen shot of the web page]

Using the above you would be able to find multiple people in the same role and allow the role to be specified by the user.

The FindPerson could be developed further to use Linq query which would be more efficient on a much larger string.